# MongoDB : update a specific field in all documents of a collection, given a specific array with just targeted field and new values

Tags: mongodb

Fairly new to MongoDB, I'm searching for the command to update a collection created like:

```
db.students.insertMany([
   { "_id": 1, "fld1": "11", "fld2": "12", "fld3": "13" },
   { "_id": 2, "fld1": "21", "fld2": "22", "fld3": "23" },
   { "_id": 3, "fld1": "31", "fld2": "32", "fld3": "33" }
])

updated with : 
[
  { "fld1": "11-new" }, { "fld1": "21-new" }, {"fld1": "31-new" }
]

giving the result: 
[
   { "_id": 1, "fld1": "11-new", "fld2": "12", "fld3": "13" },
   { "_id": 2, "fld1": "21-new", "fld2": "22", "fld3": "23" },
   { "_id": 3, "fld1": "31-new", "fld2": "32", "fld3": "33" }
]
```

I cannot seem to find this exact update type in the MongoDB doc.
db.collection.findAndModify ? db.collection.update() db.collection.updateMany() ?

Would this be considered as a bulk operation ?
providing a

```
[
{updateOne:{"filter":{"_id":1},"update":{$set:{"fld1":"11-new"}}},
{updateOne:{"filter":{"_id":2},"update":{$set:{"fld1":"21-new"}}},
{updateOne:{"filter":{"_id":3},"update":{$set:{"fld1":"31-new"}}}
]
```

Let me test this. any other simpler mean to achieve this ? Thanks

Comment: yep, the bulk operation does the job

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to update several documents with different `_id`, I suggest you use the **`bulkWrite()`** function, which takes as argument a list of operations to be performed on the collection.

In this case all the operations are **`updateOne`** queries for which you must specify the `filter` to identify the relevant document, and the `update` that must be performed on that document.

You can send this command in the Mongo Shell as follows:

```
try {
    db.students.bulkWrite([
        { 
            updateOne : {
                "filter": {"_id": "1"}, 
                "update": {"$set":{"fld1":"11-new"}}
            }
         },
         { 
            updateOne : {
                "filter": {"_id": "2"}, 
                "update": {"$set":{"fld1":"21-new"}}
            }
         },
         { 
            updateOne : {
                "filter": {"_id": "3"}, 
                "update": {"$set":{"fld1":"31-new"}}
            }
         }
    ]);
}
catch(e) { print(e); }
```

If you don't care about the order in which the operations are performed, you may also pass the optional argument `ordered` to the function and set it to false, which speeds up the execution time.

```
{ ordered : false }
```

## Script option

This second part of the answer may not be relevant to your case, but if the number of operations to be performed were very high (e.g. you have to change the fields of hundreds of documents, manually writing all the operations would be incredibly expensive. In this case, a script might be for you.

Here is an example in Python that does the following:

- connects to the mongo database and extracts the `students` collection,
- defines a function that takes two arguments: `field` and `new_values`, representing the field to be updated and an ordered list of the new values to set for that field.
- the function collects all the `_ids` currently present in the collection and builds a list of `operations` by iterating through both the ids and the new values.
- finally the bulkwrite query is sent, returning a result object that summarizes the operations performed.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, UpdateOne
client = MongoClient(your_host)
db = client["database_name"]
students = db["students"]
    
def updateCollection(field, new_values):
        
    operations = [] 
    _ids = students.distinct("_id")
    
    for _id, new_value in zip(_ids, new_values):
        operations.append(UpdateOne({"_id": _id}, {"$set":{field : new_value}}))
    
    return students.bulk_write(operations, ordered=False)
```

Following your own example, the function would be called like this:

```
updateCollection("fld1", ["11-new", "21-new", "31-new"])
```